# How to create a new gallery-album? (PHP)

Tags: php, gallery

I am - as a newbie - trying to add an album in my gallery page. Where and what code should be changed or added?

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfovci6l1she3es/func.php

Thx!!

Comment: that is a lot of unrelated code!!!!

Comment: Learning how to program or even how to use ready-made software is your responsibility. After you start learning real questions will arise. The kind of questions that stem from not understanding something you've read about as opposed to not understanding something you haven't read about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post your code **right here** next time.

A quick look at your code gives me the idea that the gallery is populated by the following piece of code:

```
$gl_type    =   Array("","1","2","3","4"); // change type here
$glm_name   =   Array("","14 November '2013","23 November '2013","15 December '2013","29 December '2013"); // modify name here **respectively**

$gl_date    =   Array("","2013","2013","2013"); // modify date here **respectively**
$gl_pic     =   Array("","2013-12-13_001_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_001_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_001_1024x768.jpg"); // modify images here **respectively**
```

Also, it looks like you can modify albums along this line:

```
switch($i){
    case "1":
        gl_pic     =   Array("","2013-12-13_001_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_002_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_003_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_004_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_005_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_006_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_007_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_008_1024x768.jpg");
        break;

    case "2":
        $gl_pic     =   Array("","2013-12-13_001_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_002_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_003_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_004_1024x768.jpg");
        break;

    case "3":
        $gl_pic     =   Array("","2013-12-13_001_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_002_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_003_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_004_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_005_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_006_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_007_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_008_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_009_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_010_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_011_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_012_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_013_1024x768.jpg");
        break;

    case "4":
        $gl_pic     =   Array("","2013-12-13_001_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_002_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_003_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_004_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_005_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_006_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_007_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_008_1024x768.jpg");
        break;

    default:
        $gl_pic     =   Array("","2013-12-13_001_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_002_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_003_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_004_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_005_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_006_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_007_1024x768.jpg","2013-12-13_008_1024x768.jpg");
    break;
}
```

Go figure the rest...

Comment: Swell! A clue.. appreciate it.

Comment: ..just in case my little clue makes it in actually solving your problem, don't forget to mark my answer as the one you have accepted ;-)

Comment: Sweet, It worked! HNY.

Comment: Glad it did ;-) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to us to develop your application, we don't produce any code, we help you in your approach.
You'll find lot of tutorials online, juste google it. e.g http://www.w3schools.com/php/

I advise you to use a database, because your code is not reusable and this is not practical.

Comment: How w3schools will help him to make application. It can only help him to learn basic php programming.

Comment: Dear Loenix. Not at all.. I'm expecting to solve it myself :)
I am very new to this though, would you be able to tell me if this gallery-function has a designation/name for me to narrow down for what I need to search? Thx.